# Is this a reliable way of returning values from a signal handler?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, signals, posix

I'd like to collect the pids of terminated subprocesses, and I had trouble communicating with the signal handler... I don't have c(++)11.
Is this valid? Please also take into consideration that my program will be multi threaded (but the queue will be used only from one thread).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <csignal>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
template<typename _ValueType, int _Capacity>
class signal_result_queue
{
public:
    static const int capacity = _Capacity;
    typedef _ValueType value_type;
private:
    //+1 so we can distinguish empty from full
    volatile value_type _data[capacity+1];
    volatile sig_atomic_t _base;
    volatile sig_atomic_t _next;
    volatile sig_atomic_t _overflows;
public:
    signal_result_queue()
    : _base(0)
    , _next(0)
    , _overflows(0)
    {}

    void push_sh(value_type value)
    {
        int base = _base; // we are not interrupted anyway
        int next = _next; // same here
        int before_base = wrap(base-1);
        if(next == before_base)
        {
            ++_overflows;
        }
        else
        {
            _data[next] = value;
            _next = wrap(next+1);
        }
    }

    int overflows_t1()
    {
        int overflows = _overflows;
        _overflows -= overflows;
        return overflows;
    }

    bool pop_t1(value_type& result)
    {
        // this is only changed by us.
        int base = _base;
        // It might increase but no problem
        int next = _next;

        if(base == next)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            result = _data[base];
            _base = wrap(base+1);
            return true;
        }
    }
private:
    static int wrap( int i )
    {
        while(i>=capacity+1)
        {
            i-=(capacity+1);
        }
        while(i<0)
        {
            i+=(capacity+1);
        }
        return i;
    }
};

signal_result_queue<pid_t, 20> q;

void sigchld_handler(int)
{
    pid_t pid;
    while((pid = waitpid(static_cast<pid_t>(-1), 0, WNOHANG)) > 0){
        q.push_sh(pid);
    }
}

int main()
{
    struct sigaction sa;
    sa.sa_handler = &sigchld_handler;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART | SA_NOCLDSTOP;
    if (sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sa, 0) == -1) {
      perror(0);
      std::exit(1);
    }

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        pid_t pid = fork();
        if(pid == 0) // child
        {
            sleep(i);
            return 0;
        }
        else if(pid == -1) // error
        {
            std::cout << "fork error" << std::endl;
        }
        else // parent
        {
            std::cout << "fork pid: " << pid <<  std::endl;
        }
    }
    int terminated = 0;
    do
    {
        sleep(1);
        int overflows = q.overflows_t1();
        if(overflows > 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Overflow in queue:" << overflows << std::endl;
        }
        pid_t val;
        while(q.pop_t1(val))
        {
            terminated++;
            std::cout << "Terminated: " << val <<  std::endl;
        }
    } while(terminated < 10);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a safe way to proceed for two reasons:

- `volatile` is not sufficient to avoid racing conditions in multithreaded programms. The sig_atomic_t are guaranteed to be atomic for signal reentrency, but I doubt that it's sufficient for multithreading.
- the use of a global queue variable is not compliant with reentrency requirements of signal handlers.

With C++11 you could use atomic instead of volatile. Without C++11, you'd need to protect concurrent access vto the queue with a [mutex lock](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_lock) protecting access to the shared variable.  This would address the two issues above.

**Additional demonstration in case of any doubt:**

Just to illustrate in more details how unsafe it is:

Suppose a fist process signal is handled:

```
    int base = _base; // acces to _base is atomic. It's protected ONLY DURING THE STATEMENT
    int next = _next; // same here
    int before_base = wrap(base-1);
```

Now imagine that another thread calls the handler, and runs on the CPU.  For simplicity, imagine that the first is put on hold by the system scheduler.   So the second instance of the handler executes:

```
    int base = _base; // SAME BASE IS STORED LOCALLY  
    int next = _next; // SAME NEXT IS STORED LOCALLY 
    int before_base = wrap(base-1);
```

So  at this moment, both instances of handler have the same indexes in their  local copies of `base` and `next`.  Now the second instance continues:

```
        ...
        _data[next] = value;   // value is stored in the queue
        _next = wrap(next+1);  // and _next is incremented.
```

Here the scheduler awakes the first instance again, which immediately continues:

```
        _data[next] = value;   // USES ITS LOCAL COPY OF NEXT, WRITE IN SAME PLACE THAN THE OTHER INSTANCE !!
        _next = wrap(next+1);  // and _next is incremented BASED ON LOCAL COPY.
```

So at this moment, in your queue, you'll have only one of the two values that should have been stored.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer. 
I didn't know that multiple signal handlers can be called while the previous is running, but it is true.
However now I read about it, and the glibc documentation says that while the signal handler for a signal is running, the same signal is blocked. So if my handler is the "subscriber" of only one signal type, and I read the queue from only one thread, than I think it is safe. (Assuming that I use glibc, and not counting the overflows variable.)
Do you agree?
http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Signals-in-Handler.html

Comment: Now I see that the overflows variable is unsafe, because the decrement _overflows -= overflows can be done in more than one instruction, and if it gets interrupted by the signal handler, which increments the value, than a smaller value may end up in _overflows then what is expected.

Comment: The mutex use you recommended is I think good provided I use 2 separate mutexes for push and pop, because if I use one, it may result in a deadlock (if "the program" locks it and then thet signal handler is called).
Also for reference this addresses the same problem, but i'm not sure it is safe either, because it modifies a data structure and uses no syncronisation, so theoretically the program may cache the earlier value of p->status. [link]http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Merged-Signals.html#Merged-Signals

Comment: The glibc seems indeed safe in this regard.  The posix documentation howeer advises use of programmatic syncrhonisation for non re-entrant code (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sigaction.html).  I believe you should have one mutext preventing access to both push and pop (otherwise you could still have racing conditions).  Deadlock should not occur here, as you'd have only one protected zone in each of the two operations.

Comment: But consider I lock the mutex in the pop method, and then the signal handler gets called on the same thread. The signal handler will try to lock the same mutex, but it can't since it is already locked.

Answer (score 0):

My friend solved it, he only increments a volatile sig_atomic_t when the signal occurs, and uses the waitpid in the MAIN thread.
It is so simple. I saw a code which calls waitpid in the signal handler and I didn't realize it could be called later in the main thread.
There is no need for this queue.